# Каким образом можно сделать view, на подобии Make a call в iPhone?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

[image]

Всем привет !

Я только начал разбираться с основами разработки приложений под `iOS`, но вот назрел вопрос:

есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение, что бы добиться такого `View` ?

Если нету, может кто нибудь подскажет хорошее **пособие** для прочтения, что бы можно было сделать подобное.

Спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гляньте, к примеру, [вот это готовое решенеие](https://github.com/jconst/JCDialPad)

Чтобы самому сделать - расставьте кнопки и измените у них `cornerRadius` и `borderWidth`+`borderColor`

Comment: Спасибо за готовое решение ! ;)